# How can I write string to container to be used after a loop?

Tags: java, mysql, io

I have an aplication which create a number of query (update or insert) and then each query is executed.

The whole code is working fine but I've saw that my server IO latency is too much during this proccess.

The code execute a loop which is taking arround 1 minute.

Then what I wanted to do is write each query in memory instead to execute it, and then, once I have the whole list of query to execute, use "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" from mysql, which will take less time.

My question is: How can I write all my query (String object) in a "File" or "any other container" in java to use it after the loop?.

@user3283548 This is my example code:

Class1:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Class1 {



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<String> Staff=new ArrayList<String>();
    Staff.add("tom");
    Staff.add("Laura");
    Staff.add("Patricia");
     for (int x = 0; x < Staff.size(); x++) {
         System.out.println(Staff.get(x));
         Class2 user = new Class2 (Staff.get(x));
         user.checkUser();

     }
}

}
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2 {

private String user;

 public Class2(String user){
     this.user=user;
 }
 public void checkUser() throws Exception{

 if (user.equals("tom")){
         String queryUser="update UsersT set userStatus='2' where UserName='"+user+"';";
         Class3 updateUser = new Class3(queryUser);
         updateUser.UpdateQuery();;
 }else{
         String queryUser="Insert into UsersT (UserName,userStatus)Values('"+user+"','1');";
         Class3 updateUser = new Class3(queryUser);
         updateUser.InsertQuery();
         System.out.println(user+" is not ton doing new insert");
 }

 }   
}
```

Class3:

```
 public class Class3 {
    public String Query;

    public Class3(String Query){
        this.Query = Query;
    }

    public void UpdateQuery() throws Exception{ 

    /*// Accessing Driver From Jar File
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    //DB Connection
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/default","root","1234567");
    String sql =Query;
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);*/

    System.out.println(Query); //Just to test

    //pst.execute();
}
    public void InsertQuery() throws Exception{ 

        /*// Accessing Driver From Jar File
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //DB Connection
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/default","root","1234567");
        String sql =Query;
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);*/

        System.out.println(Query); //Just to test

        //pst.execute();
    }
}
```

Then, what I wanted to do is create an ArraList in Class1 and use it in Class3 to collect all the queries which has to be executed.

The idea is to execute the list of queries in one time, once the main process is finished,  istead to do it for each element within in loop of the Class1. I wanted to do it, because I think it will be take less resource IO from the server HD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is probably too slow because you're building up Strings using String

I'd hazard a guess you're doing things like

`String query = "SELECT * FROM " + variablea + " WHERE + variableb + " = " ...`

If you're doing a lot of string concatenation then use `StringBuilder` as every time you change a string it is actually re-created which is expensive. Simply changing your code to use StringBuilder instead of string will probably cut your loop executed time to a couple of MS. Simply call `.toString()` method of `StringBuilder obj` to get the string.

**Storing objects**

If you want to store anything for later use you should store it in a `Collection`. If you want a a key-value relationship then use a `Map` (HashMap would suit you fine). If you just want the values use an `List` (`ArrayList` is most popular).

So for example if I wanted to store query strings for later use I would...

1. Construct the string using StringBuilder.
2. Put the string (by calling .toString() into a HashMap
3. Get the query string from the HashMap...

You should never store things on disk if you don't need them to be persistent over application restarts and even then I'd store them in a database not in a file.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

David

**EDIT: UPDATE BASED ON YOU POSTING YOUR CODE:**

OK this needs some major re-factoring!

I've kept it really simple because I don't have a lot of time to re-write comprehensively.

I've commented where I have made corrections.

Your major issue here is creating objects in loops. You should just create the object once as creating objects is expensive.

I've also corrected other coding issues and replaced the for loop as you shouldn't be writing it like that.I've also renamed the classes to something useful.

I've not tested this so you may need to do some work to get it to work. But this should be a lot faster.

OLD CLASS 1

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StaffChecker {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Creating objects is expensive, you should do this as little as possible
    StaffCheckBO staffCheckBO = new StaffCheckBO();

    // variables should be Camel Cased and describe what they hold
    // Never start with ArrayList start with List you should specific the interface on the left side.
    List<String> staffList = new ArrayList<String>();
    staffList.add("tom");
    staffList.add("Laura");
    staffList.add("Patricia");

    // use a foreach loop not a (int x = 0 ... ) This is the preffered method.
    for (String staffMember : staffList) {
        // You now dont need to use .get() you can access the current variable using staffMember
        System.out.println(staffMember);

        // Do the work
        staffCheckBO.checkUser(staffMember);
    }
  }
}
```

OLD CLASS 2

```
/**
 * Probably not really any need for this class but I'll assume further business logic may follow.
 */
public class StaffCheckBO {

// Again only create our DAO once...CREATING OBJECTS IS EXPENSIVE.
private StaffDAO staffDAO = new StaffDAO();

public void checkUser(String staffMember) throws Exception{

 boolean staffExists = staffDAO.checkStaffExists(staffMember);

     if(staffExists) {
         System.out.println(staffMember +" is not in database, doing new insert.");
         staffDAO.insertStaff(staffMember);
     } else {
         System.out.println(staffMember +" has been found in the database, updating user.");
         staffDAO.updateStaff(staffMember);
     }
   }
}
```

OLD CLASS 3

```
import java.sql.*;

/**
 * You will need to do some work to get this class to work fully and this is obviously     basic but its to give you an idea.
 */
public class StaffDAO {

public boolean checkStaffExists(String staffName) {
    boolean staffExists = false;

    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM STAFF_TABLE WHERE STAFF_NAME = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(query);

        // Load your variables into the string in order to be safe against injection attacks.
        preparedStatement.setString(1, staffName);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        // If a record has been found the staff member is in the database. This obviously doesn't account for multiple staff members
        if(resultSet.next()) {
            staffExists = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception in getStaff: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return staffExists;
}

// Method names should be camel cased
public void updateStaff(String staffName) throws Exception {

    try {
        String query = "YOUR QUERY";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(query);

        // Load your variables into the string in order to be safe against injection attacks.
        preparedStatement.setString(1, staffName);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception in getStaff: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void insertStaff(String staffName) throws Exception {

    try {
        String query = "YOUR QUERY";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getDBConnection().prepareStatement(query);

        // Load your variables into the string in order to be safe against injection attacks.
        preparedStatement.setString(1, staffName);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception in getStaff: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}


/**
 * You need to abstract the connection logic away so you avoid code reuse.
 *
 * @return
 */
private Connection getDBConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/default", "root", "1234567");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find class. DB Connection could not be created: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception. " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return connection;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits Rembo. First post so I'll be sure to enclose code inside code blocks correctly next time :).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Regarding the String, is not exactly my problem since I have to create just 100 of String not more. The time is spent because inside the loop I'm calling others class which take a bit time to do some others operation. But anyway I didnt know it and sure I will use it in other parts of my code. Just let me share this clear example (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html)

Comment: Regarding the Storing Objects: I got it, I can use a ArrayList and then use it afterward. But my problem now is that the loop in my main class is calling other class which doesn't return anything, those second class do some operation and then call to my Update_Databse_Class directly to execute the query in my database. Is there any way to create an ArrayList in my main class that it coul be used for anyother class until it will be deleted/destroyed/removed/closed or whatever.

Comment: Hi, Please post a code example and I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my Question with a example code. I've google it and I found out some way to do it (creating interface or a simple ArrayList declaration as a global and import it in CLass3  but, I dont know why, I'm getting an error of "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Updated my answer. Your classes needed a bit of work. Hopefully this will help you understand some further java coding concepts.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your time. Now is much more clear for me. Just a question, you point out to load my variable in stream to be save against SQL injection, but if every query is done from the core of the appliction, it doesn't have any connection with the external WEb part, following MVC model. Even that, do you think it's good idea to carry out this practice?

Comment: Hello! Yes This is standard practice. It does prevent injection but is also easier to read etc.